# Javascript, Class, Methods, Function , How to not repeat code?

Tags: javascript, es6-class

1. How to not repeat code ?
2. someExampleSetupFunction(); is same output if i < par1,par2...parN
3. In for loop it repeat calculations of this function parN times per Array

So question is same how to make less calculations ?

```
class Example{
   constructor(exampleArray){
      this.exampleArray = exampleArray;
   }
   function exampleMethod(){
       let i = 0;
       for(i = 0; i < this.exampleArray.length; i++){
           if(i < par1){ // par1 times same setup
              someExampleSetupFunction(); /* already calculated if i > 0 ,
              so how to bring it out ?*/
              someOperations(); // setup values changed.
           }else if(i < par2){ // par2 times same setup
              someExampleSetupFunction(); /* already calculated if i > par1,
              so how to bring it out ?*/
              someOperations2(); // setup values changed
           }...
           ...else if(i < this.exampleArray.length){
              someExampleSetupFunction();
              someOperationsN(); // setup values changed
           }
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Sorry , maybe I was wrong , seems like I can`t get less calculations only I can get is less letters in code . someExampleSetupFunction() - changes everytime after i changes and also changes after someOperations(), In someExampleSetupFunction()  -  there are 4 if statements that depends on index "i"

Answer (score 0):

Like this, perhaps?

Note that I've changed `someExampleSetupFunction` to an arrow function because the way you were calling it would have caused it to lose the `this` context.

```
class Example{
   constructor(exampleArray){
      this.exampleArray = exampleArray;
   }
   exampleMethod (){
       let i = 0;
       const operations = [
           someOperations,
           someOperations2,
           someOperations3,
           someOperations4
       ];

       const someExampleSetupFunction = () => {
          if(this.exampleArray[i] === "param1"){
             // do something...
          }else if(this.exampleArray[i] === "param2"){
             // do something else...
          }
       }
       for(i = 0; i < this.exampleArray.length; i++){
           operations.forEach((op) => {
               someExampleSetupFunction();
               op();
           });
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok. first, in your code, when you are doing...

```
for(i = 0; i < this.exampleArray.length; i++){
           someExampleSetupFunction();
           someOperations();
           someExampleSetupFunction();
           someOperations2();
           someExampleSetupFunction();
           someOperations3();
           someExampleSetupFunction();
           someOperations4();
       }
```

this is called **RECURSION** and the problem with this is that it decreases the performance and level up time execution. you had better avoid this to make good practices.

The best way you can avoid recursion is using a **buttom-up** code practice and with this way save the memory cost that recursion incurs when it builds up the call stack.

```
let result = <result>;

for(i = 0; i < this.exampleArray.length; i++){
           //Some operations that return a <result>
           result += <result>;
       }
```

here is a [link](http://www.programmingforbeginnersbook.com/blog/top-down-bottom-up-approaches-to-learning-programming/) for more details about bottom-up practice